# How to search Wordpress User by Username or First name on frontend?

Tags: wordpress, frontend

This is my code but didnt get desired result.I just want to search out the specific user by its first_name and its role is it_guy.  Anyone please help.

```
$users = new WP_User_Query( 
    array( 

        'role' => 'it_guy',
        'meta_key' => 'first_name',
        'search'  => '*'.esc_attr( $your_search_string ).'*',
        'orderby' => 'first_name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'offset' => '',
        'number' => '',

));


foreach($users as $user)
    {
         <?php echo $user->first_name; ?>
    }
```

Comment: If you do not get the desired results, make your expected output clear and provide the "wrong" output

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(
        array(
                'role' => 'it_guy',
                'meta_key' => 'first_name',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'offset' => '',
                'number' => '',
                'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                                'key'     => 'first_name',
                                'value'   => esc_attr( $your_search_string ),
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                )
        )
);
```